# After wipe data unable to open emulator it shows Emulator process for AVD was killed

Tags: react-native, android-emulator

I have wipe out the data in emulator to fix the internet connectivity issue with the emulator. After this action I can't able to open the emulator.

So I tried deleting the AVD and created new one. **It not worked**
Tried to open from command line. It falied

If I tried via command line it shows **Not enough space to create userdata partition. Available: 4251.667969 MB at /Users/name/.android/avd/Pixel_XL_API_30.avd, need 7372.800000 MB**

Here why this shows space issues when I tried to open from command line and why it shows the Emulator process for AVD was killed in Android studio?

I tried this to fix the internet issue, but nothing worked
**emulator @Nexus_S_API_30 -dns-server 8.8.8.8**

Tried this solution **but it not worked**

```
Go to: Tools > Android > AVD Manager.
Press the "edit" (pencil) icon next to your AVD.
Change "Graphics" to "Software".
```

Restarted the machine, it not worked

Answer (score 0):

Check the Android SDK PATH you are using. It must be the same you have in Android Studio

mine:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/fsilva/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$ANDROID_HOME
export ANDROIDNDK=$ANDROID_HOME/ndk-bundle
```